# UK tourist visa - Marriage certificate

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I am from India, planning to travel to UK for tourism with my wife. I read somewhere that laminated documents cause issue. Our marriage certificate is laminated. Will it be fine with VFS while scanning? Also, the marriage certificate is in both local language and English. Which means I need not provide any translation doc, right?

Comment: I don't have any proof or evidence, but in my opinion it should just be fine. It is not that big of a deal to have a marriage certificate that is laminated, while applying for a standard tourist visa.

Comment: I don’t think a marriage certificate is particularly relevant for a visitor visa application, and I don’t recall seeing any guidance mentioning laminated documents. If it’s in both local language and English no additional translation is needed (what would be the point?)

Answer (score 2):

I've had important documents such as a birth certificate laminated before and it did cause problems. It should be accepted as it doesn't have to be stamped or anything. If you want to get a copy as laminated documents make it really hard to detect important security features.

On a side note I found this on the [UK GOV website relating to a passport application](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/118574/Gen-info-application-types.pdf):

> IPS regional offices have a very small percentage of applications supported
>   by laminated documents. Documents that are laminated are usually birth
>   certificates, marriage certificates and naturalisation/registration certificates.
>
> IPS examiners cannot be sure that the laminated documents submitted with
>   an application are genuine.
>
> Major concerns regarding laminated documents are that watermarks cannot
>   be easily distinguished, nor can the quality of the paper be felt, and with
>   naturalisation/registration certificate the security features such as the heat
>   reactive number cannot be utilised.
>
> **Laminated documents must not be accepted in support of passport
>   applications, unless in cases covered by the exceptions shown below.
>   Examiners must request unlaminated versions of the documents submitted.**

Whilst that is relating to passports it shows the UK can be strict on laminated documents so it might be better to request a un-laminated copy.